# Accidentally banged car lightly against house wall. How to remove car paint and other marks?

Tags: walls, cleaning

Kind of a beginner driver here. This morning as I was backing up out the garage I accidentally got off track and banged the back of the car lightly against a wall. No structural damage, it only got scratched. **My question is how to clean the car paint and other marks from the wall without having the whole thing painted again**.

The wall is made of brick and has a nice coat of light beige paint. My car is red, so now it's marked with red and black scratches. I don't mean to recover it fully, I'm only looking for a make do, low cost approach to cleaning the big stuff.

Love and respect to the community.

Comment: Any chance of a picture?  Something like a "magic eraser" might work well for this, but it depends on the severity.

Comment: Water some soft soap and and a cloth or soft brush, add some elbow grease.  Car paint should only be struck to building paint, not bonded.

Comment: Do you have any leftover paint originally used to paint the wall on hand?

Comment: @JPhi1618 I'll be looking into that magic eraser thing. Didn't even know it existed. I'll be giving an update maybe tonight, maybe tomorrow. Tomorrow morning i'll be posting a picture.